# Can't connect WiFi printer to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, printing, 19.10

A quick question. I have my old printer connected to my Ubuntu laptop. It's a WiFi printer. Epson WF-3620. I just bought a new printer, Epson ET-4700 and I am having a heck of a time getting it to connect with my laptop. It is connected to the WiFi. I am able to print to it using the email address the printer set up during initial setup but I can't not get it to print from my computer. I have tried to mimic my other printer's settings but that isn't working either. I have also downloaded and installed the drivers and software from Epson. I'm also able to print to the new printer using the USB (finally after 5 hours of messing with it) but I'm not always connected to the printer or even in the same room.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Epson printers are supposed to be connected to your router, not directly to your laptop. The printer gets an IP address and you can setup printing using this address.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your printer is connected to your router by Wi-Fi, because it has internet access. You need to find out it's local IP address. There must be a way to get this information from the printer: either by LED if there is one, or to print network settings.

After you know the IP address, you can add a network printer in Ubuntu. Network search doesn't work out well.

You don't need to "connect" the printer to your laptop if you have standard network settings where all clients are in the same sub net and have access to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It's just possible that your router doesn't support as many WIFI devices that you have which can cause all sorts of problems. You can check with your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pilot6 and Christopher for your responses. I fixed the problem. It works now that I connected the printer the 2.4Gz instead of 5Gz WiFi. I'm not sure why the 5Gz doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like clients form 2.4 can't access 5 GHz, etc. This is all about your router settings.